# Burp suite rest webservice callout

Tags: rest-api, security-review, burp

We have been asked to do a BURP Scan of our Salesforce app during security review. Our application is built completely on Force.com platform but we have 1-2 REST webservice calls to external server. Please help on how to use BURP Suite to scan these webservice calls.

Answer (score 1):

BURP scanning is required for any & all external web components.

To use BURP testing on an API/web service, you want to simulate API calls through BURP using SoapUI, Curl, or a similar tool.

1. If you don't have it already you should submit a case through
   you ISV partner account to get a free BURP scanner license, or go
   [here](https://security.secure.force.com/apex/security_tools_webapp_scanner_request).
2. Download and Install, then follow this [tutorial](http://security.force.com/security/tools/webapp/burptut).

This will require you to intercept and/or simulate calls to the external service via the scanner to look for vulnerabilities.

I usually simulate the calls to the endpoint from a tool such as [Runscope.com](https://www.runscope.com/) or [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/), and intercept these with Burp scanner. Burp Scanner can the replay then as needed to perform the full scan.